# Guide me to build ad server using Pylons

Tags: pylons, advertisement-server

Building advertising infrastructure for each website is somewhat bad, especially when the website is new and not much traffic. People will curious to advertise to website with low traffic.

I need ad server (like AdSense) which:

- user can register, can create an ad
  (advertiser), and can embed customizable ad codes in
  their website
- have text and image ads
- all payment through paypal

I've found some example using Pylons but it rather outdated. It will be great if someone can guide me what to do and what I need to build it. Any recommendation are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for good documented pylons framework you should look at [PylonsProject](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/) aka [Pyramid](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/docs/pyramid.html). Here you will find EVERYTHING up-2-date documentation. So i think this is a good start.

But if you are looking for a website that you install, login and start working this is not what you want. with pylons/pyramid you will have to write your own code.

Also if you are more explicit where you need guidance i will be more helpful.